# php simple caching class

Tags: php, caching

I'm using [this](http://devgrow.com/simple-cache-class/) simple PHP caching class in my script.

It's working fine but the problem arises when I make change in to the database like adding comments, login or any other change, it doesn't appear on the page.

So, is there anything I can do to solve this problem.

Comment: *Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.*

Answer (score 0):

http://devgrow.com/simple-cache-class/

Shows a function called purge - passing in the location. Would it be possible to get the location and purge it on a DB update.

Taken from the site:

> The last two functions are used for deleting cache files. The purge function takes a location (full URL for now) and marks it for deletion"